# Regex to validate subtract equations like "abc-b=ac"

Tags: regex, pcre

I've stumbled upon a regex question.

How to validate a *subtract equation* like this?

A string subtract another string equals to whatever remains(all the terms are just plain strings, not sets. So `ab` and `ba` are different strings).

#### Pass

- `abc-b=ac`
- `abcde-cd=abe`
- `ab-a=b`
- `abcde-a=bcde`
- `abcde-cde=ab`

#### Fail

- `abc-a=c`
- `abcde-bd=ace`
- `abc-cd=ab`
- `abcde-a=cde`
- `abc-abc=`
- `abc-=abc`

Here's what I tried and you may play around with it

https://regex101.com/r/lTWUCY/1/

Comment: If you want to parse simple expressions, you probably also want to parse compound expressions like `abc-(def-ghi)` and then `abc-(de-(fg-hi-(ij-kl)))` at which point regular expressions will be unsuitable for the task anyway. You want a parser.

Comment: @tripleee I would say it's more like a puzzle to explore what regex is capable of, and how elegant it could be. This question may not be practical, but it was fun to solve it, and I learned a lot by doing so :)

Comment: What is `abc-abc` if blank is a fail?

Comment: a) Why is `abcde-bd=ace` a fail? b) Do terms have to be in order? `abc-ca=b`? c) Can you subtract more than exist on the LHS: `abc-ca-a=...`?

Comment: @smci a) Because `abcde` does not contain string `bd` b) Yes, the terms must not be scrambled  c) No,  there are only three terms `minuend-subtrahend=difference` and each term cannot be empty

Comment: @HaoWu: ok, I recommend you add those terms into your question. Because it's not clear that it's a substring subtraction, not a set subtraction.

Comment: @smci thanks for the advice and I added that as an additional  disclaimer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I see that some of the comments were deleted. So let me start by saying that, though short (in terms of code-golf), the following answer is *not* the most efficient in terms of steps involved. Though, looking at the nature of the question and its "puzzle" aspect, it will probably do fine. For a more efficient answer, I'd like to redirect you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66813440/9758194) answer.

---

Here is my attempt:

```
^(.*)(.+)(.*)-\2=(?=.)\1\3$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4Fwv8V/1)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(.*)` - A 1st capture group with 0+ non-newline characters right upto;
- `(.+)` - A 2nd capture group with 1+ non-newline characters right upto;
- `(.*)` - A 3rd capture group with 0+ non-newline characters right upto;
- `-\2=` - An hyphen followed by a backreference to our 2nd capture group and a literal "=".
- `(?=.)` - A positive lookahead to assert position is followed by at least a single character other than newline.
- `\1\3` - A backreference to what was captured in both the 1st and 3rd capture group.
- `$` - End line anchor.

---

**EDIT:**

I guess a bit more restrictive could be:

```
^([a-z]*)([a-z]+)((?1))-\2=(?=.)\1\3$
```

Answer (score 13):

You may use this more efficient regex with a lookahead at the start with a capture group that matches text on the right hand side of `-` i.e. substring between `-` and `=` and captures it in group #1. Then in the main body of regex we just check presence of capture group #1 and capture text before and after `\1` in 2 separate groups.

```sh
^(?=[^-]+-([^=]+)=.)([^-]*?)\1([^-]*)-[^=]+=\2\3$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lTWUCY/4)

**RegEx Demo:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?=[^-]+-([^=]+)=.)`: Lookahead to make sure we have expression structure of `pqr-pq=r` and also **more importantly** capture substring between `-` and `=` in capture group #1. `.` after `=` is there for a reason to disallow any empty string after `=`.
- `([^-]*?)`: Match 0 or more non-`-` characters in capture group #2
- `\1`: Back-reference to group #1 to make sure we match same value as in capture group #1
- `([^-]*)`: Match 0 or more non-`-` characters in capture group #3
- `-`: Match a `-`
- `[^=]+`: Match 0 or more non-`=` characters
- `=`: Match a `=`
- `\2\3`: Back-reference to group #2 and #3 which is difference of substraction
- `$`: End

Comment: This is quite mindblowing. But maybe restrictions like `[^-]` are not not necessary for validations? Since if `.` fails, `[^-]` would fail anyway... Or this is just for better performance?

Comment: Indeed `[^-]*` performs much faster than `.*`

Comment: btw there is nothing PCRE in this, this will work same in Java, Python, Javascript etc as well

Comment: @anubhava that **is ~PCRE**. Only because the regexen in those languages were made to conform to the Perl syntax. The `(?=...)` is the perlism. Also, that is not a **regular expression** in the mathematical / Kleene sense. Not that it matters here :P

Comment: That I agree on mathematical part but what I meant that same regex will work fine on Java, Python, Javascript as well that are not PCRE

Comment: Indeed `[^-]*?` was for reducing backtracking which will reduce backtracking for most of the cases shown in question.

Comment: Your solutions keep on amazing me, I did not think of / see this before but that is really clever ++++.